# Arrange images in grid using html and CSS

Tags: html, css

I have the following code in place

https://jsfiddle.net/pensee/pyb1oawt/24/

I tried to put the images and some styling but couldn't make it like on the page 
https://store.linefriends.com/ 
There are 5 images on this page under the heading **New Collections** 
The small html that I have created also has 5 images but they appear vertically and not like 
stacked up on the page. I am not really sure how to go about doing it.

Posting the HTML and CSS from the Jsfiddle here too for reference :

```css
* {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.promo_banner {
  background-color: #333;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 12px;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 5000;
  top: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
div.logo {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
} 
div.mySlides img{ 
  width: 40% !important;
  margin-left: 30%;
}
div.logo img {
  max-width: 205px;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.nav .menu {
  display: flex;
  gap: 1rem;
  list-style: none;
}
.nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
.nav_wrapper {
  background: #f1f1f1;
}
.nav .menu li {
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 12px 0;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
.nav .menu li.active {
  color: green;
}
.nav .menu li:hover {
  color: green;
  border-bottom: 1px solid green;
}

.contents_title {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  height: 10px;
}
.line {
  flex-grow: 1;
  margin-left: 20px;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #333;
}
/* Slideshow container */
.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}

/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev,
.next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  padding: 16px;
  margin-top: -22px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
}

/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
.prev:hover,
.next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

/* Caption text */
.text {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Number text (1/3 etc) */
.numbertext {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

/* The dots/bullets/indicators */
.dot {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.active,
.dot:hover {
  background-color: #717171;
}

/* Fading animation */
.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {
    opacity: 0.4;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {
    opacity: 0.4;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

/* On smaller screens, decrease text size */
@media only screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  .prev,
  .next,
  .text {
    font-size: 11px;
  }
}
.shg-row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  min-height: inherit;
  max-height: inherit;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Kittens</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
<div class="shg-row" data-col-grid-mode-on="">
      <div class="shg-c-lg-6 shg-c-md-6 shg-c-sm-6 shg-c-xs-12">
        <div class="shg-box-vertical-align-wrapper">
          <div
            class="shg-box shg-c"
            id="s-cd25fc77-28ea-45a7-b683-2cffe168ca45"
          >
            <div class="shg-box-overlay"></div>
            <div class="shg-box-content">
              <div
                class="
                  shg-c
                  shogun-image-container shogun-image-linked
                  shg-align-center
                "
                style=""
                id="s-c5c157da-acba-4d5d-a09f-31edb371a702"
              >
                <img
                  alt="home-1"
                  src="https://i.ibb.co/Bnhb5MG/home-1.jpg"
                  class="shogun-image"
                />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="shg-c-lg-6 shg-c-md-6 shg-c-sm-6 shg-c-xs-12">
        <div class="shg-c" id="s-fc143b42-5d16-4f78-8b30-e0076397a038">
          <div class="shg-row" data-col-grid-mode-on="">
            <div class="shg-c-lg-6 shg-c-md-6 shg-c-sm-6 shg-c-xs-12">
              <div
                class="
                  shg-c
                  shogun-image-container shogun-image-linked
                  shg-align-center
                "
                id="s-473767af-0ae6-477a-99aa-34b88b50ccc3"
              >
                <img
                  alt="home-2"
                  class="shogun-image shogun-lazyloaded"
                  src="https://i.ibb.co/5csM0mB/home-2.jpg"
                />
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="shg-c-lg-6 shg-c-md-6 shg-c-sm-6 shg-c-xs-12">
              <div
                class="
                  shg-c
                  shogun-image-container shogun-image-linked
                  shg-align-center
                "
                id="s-aeda953a-d6c9-43d0-af79-2a147510b9e1"
              >
                <img
                  alt="home-3"
                  class="shogun-image shogun-lazyloaded"
                  src="https://i.ibb.co/RTkBRH7/home-3.jpg"
                />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="shg-c" id="s-7dcad350-4935-4067-9151-0e40a74a0293">
          <div class="shg-row" data-col-grid-mode-on="">
            <div class="shg-c-lg-6 shg-c-md-6 shg-c-sm-6 shg-c-xs-12">
              <div
                class="
                  shg-c
                  shogun-image-container shogun-image-linked
                  shg-align-center
                "
                id="s-74f6f2a8-3296-445f-8a98-681f7a8f599d"
              >
                <img
                  alt="home-4"
                  class="shogun-image shogun-lazyloaded"
                  src="https://i.ibb.co/Nm7JcYn/home-4.jpg"
                />
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="shg-c-lg-6 shg-c-md-6 shg-c-sm-6 shg-c-xs-12">
              <div
                class="
                  shg-c
                  shogun-image-container shogun-image-linked
                  shg-align-center
                "
                id="s-2451ce00-7a9c-4bb1-9bc2-90e120b4ca6a"
              >
                <img
                  src="https://i.ibb.co/FhNn7Xg/home-5.jpg"
                  alt="home-5"
                  class="shogun-image"
                />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script src="js/slide-show.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: There is actually `display: grid` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout) which will probably make your life easier.

Answer (score 0):

I made a template for you to customize and re-use for other projects if you wish.
the "gallery" class is your main grid container where the rows and columns are defined 
 
 grid-template: repeat(7, 5vw)/repeat(8, 1fr);
meaning 7 rows 5 vw each 

8 columns each 
1 fractional unit 1fr is 1 part of the available space 

each grid item is defined as grid-row and grid-column which you can adjust the "spans" and the start and end numbers. as-well as simply deleting what you don't need.

the gallery__img class is so each img takes up the entire grid space.

hope this helps some...

```css
.gallery {
  background-color: #f9f7f6;
  grid-column: full-start / full-end;
  display: grid;
  /*grid-template-columns: repeat(8, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(7, 5vw);*/
  grid-template: repeat(7, 5vw)/repeat(8, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 1.5rem;
  padding: 1.5rem;
}

.gallery__item--1 {
  grid-row: 1 / span 2;
  grid-column: 1 / span 2;
  background: black;
}

.gallery__item--2 {
  grid-row: 1 / span 3;
  grid-column: 3 / span 3;
  background: yellow;
}

.gallery__item--3 {
  grid-row: 1 / span 2;
  grid-column: 6 / 7;
  background: orange;
}

.gallery__item--4 {
  grid-row: 1 / span 2;
  grid-column: 7 / -1;
  background: blue;
}

.gallery__item--5 {
  grid-row: 3 / span 3;
  grid-column: 1 / span 2;
  background: purple;
}

.gallery__item--6 {
  grid-row: 4 / span 2;
  grid-column: 3 / span 2;
  background: red;
}

.gallery__item--7 {
  grid-row: 4 / 5;
  grid-column: 5 / 6;
  background: green;
}

.gallery__item--8 {
  grid-row: 3 / span 2;
  grid-column: 6 / span 2;
  background: brown;
}

.gallery__item--9 {
  grid-row: 3 / span 3;
  grid-column: 8 / -1;
  background: teal;
}

.gallery__item--10 {
  grid-row: 6 / span 2;
  grid-column: 1 / 2;
  background: magenta;
}

.gallery__item--11 {
  grid-row: 6 / span 2;
  grid-column: 2 / span 2;
  background: black;
}

.gallery__item--12 {
  grid-row: 6 / span 2;
  grid-column: 4 / 5;
  background: brown;
}

.gallery__item--13 {
  grid-row: 5 / span 3;
  grid-column: 5 / span 3;
  background: lightblue;
}

.gallery__item--14 {
  grid-row: 6 / span 2;
  grid-column: 8 / -1;
  background: pink;
}

.gallery__img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<section class="gallery">
  <figure class="gallery__item gallery__item--1"><img src="" alt="Gallery image 1" class="gallery__img"></figure>
  <figure class="gallery__item gallery__item--2"><img src="" alt="Gallery image 2" class="gallery__img"></figure>
  <figure class="gallery__item gallery__item--3"><img src="" alt="Gallery image 3" class="gallery__img"></figure>
  <figure class="gallery__item gallery__item--4"><img src="" alt="Gallery image 4" class="gallery__img"></figure>
  <figure class="gallery__item gallery__item--5"><img src="" alt="Gallery image 5" class="gallery__img"></figure>
  <figure class="gallery__item gallery__item--6"><img src="" alt="Gallery image 6" class="gallery__img"></figure>
  <figure class="gallery__item gallery__item--7"><img src="" alt="Gallery image 7" class="gallery__img"></figure>
  <figure class="gallery__item gallery__item--8"><img src="" alt="Gallery image 8" class="gallery__img"></figure>
  <figure class="gallery__item gallery__item--9"><img src="" alt="Gallery image 9" class="gallery__img"></figure>
  <figure class="gallery__item gallery__item--10"><img src="" alt="Gallery image 10" class="gallery__img"></figure>
  <figure class="gallery__item gallery__item--11"><img src="" alt="Gallery image 11" class="gallery__img"></figure>
  <figure class="gallery__item gallery__item--12"><img src="" alt="Gallery image 12" class="gallery__img"></figure>
  <figure class="gallery__item gallery__item--13"><img src="" alt="Gallery image 13" class="gallery__img"></figure>
  <figure class="gallery__item gallery__item--14"><img src="" alt="Gallery image 14" class="gallery__img"></figure>
</section>
```